# Creating large file ties up memory after process is done

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04LTS server (AWS EC2) to do a custom database dump but I'm getting a very odd memory behavior.

I'm using PHP CLI script to loop through the custom dump query that outputs to a numbered file then `cat` that file into the output file. The memory usage climbs as expected because of the mysql. The mysql dump file and the output file are all written to a separate mounted drive (EBS).

Before starting the script the memory usage is about 20%. Once the process is done the memory usage is about 90% based on graphs in `htop`. I've verified the usage with `free -m`. A mysql restart drops the memory usage down to about 50%.

I've used `lsof` to verify that nothing is using the file. I've even done `lsof` on the directory and only get my bash process and lsof.

The really weird part is as soon as I delete the file the memory usage drops back to 20%.

I've tried deleting the file without restarting mysql and the usage drops by the 30% the numbers above would expect.

Using the memory viewer script found [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts) does not show the same memory usage so I assume it's not completely accurate. It shows no memory consumption by keeping the file.

Is there some other way I can tell what is holding the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're actually looking at is the system's disk cache usage.  All modern system will cache disk operations to make recurrent access of the same disk area faster.

This caching process is considered to cost very little resource for the frequent benefits it may generate later.  Since the system knows that the cache is not important compared to any other memory requirement, it will instantly dump parts of it should it be needed for something else.

You are also noticing the MySQL server process' internal caching which will act similar to the operating system's cache, but the OS does not recognize this as cache, which is why it is only freed based on operations through the server process itself, such as restarting it.

Comment: Disk cache seemed to be exactly what it was. Looking for a flush I came to `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` which immediately dropped it back down. Kind of annoying when the instance reports memory usage and it doesn't drop back down.

Comment: @DavidFairbanks Use that command very sparingly, as it will nearly always *decrease* the performance of your server.

Comment: @EEAA I understand and it does feel like a hack. I't only used during the script execution which only happens once a month. I wish there was a way to temporarily disable it for a process.

Comment: Disk caching by process is not possible because the memory that would be needed just to track which process uses which part of the cache would drastically increase the cache's memory usage and decrease CPU performance.

Comment: You worry too much on something that will not impact your server's operations.  You should probably look at a better approach to monitoring the usage than considering the cache usage as a problem.

Comment: @DavidFairbanks I agree 100% with Julie. You do not need to worry about this type of memory usage. The cache consumed by this file will be **immediately** given up to any process that tries to allocate RAM. Additionally, after the dump, as your system reads other files, those will gradually replace the dump file in cache. Life is too short to worry about this sort of thing. Let the kernel's memory management routines so what they're good at.

Comment: Thanks EEAA and Julie, that's exactly why I put the question up. I was getting crashing but I guess that was handled with the mysql changes. Looking at the memory stats got me worried that a production server would crash. Trying the full job it does in fact run now.